# How to handle nested subscriptions in Spring webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project, project-reactor

I have a requirement in which I need to perform a sequence of 3 method calls each of which returns a Mono.

```
   Mono<WeightResponse> weightService() 
   Mono<PriceResponse> priceService(WeightResponse wr) 
   Mono<DispatchResponse> dispatchService(PriceResponse pr)
```

These 3 method calls need to be done in chronological order.

This is what I have tried to come up with. I am yet to compete and test this functionality end to end. I am looking for advice on how to handle this type of scenario in Spring Reactor?
There is subscription inside subscription inside subscription. Is this the right approach to handle such a scenario?
Could there be any side effects of such nested subscriptions?

```
weightService().subscribe(wr -> {
      priceService(wr).subscribe (pr -> {
        dispatchService(pr).subscribe (dr -> {
            System.out.println("Dispatch Done!");
          },
          e -> log.error("error in dispatch {}", e);
        );
       },
       e -> log.error("error in pricing {}", e);
      );
     },
     e -> log.error("error in weight calculation {}", e);
   );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not subscribe explicitly. Typically you need to construct reactive flow and the framework like `spring-webflux` will subscribe to it.

In the following example `flatMap` would subscribe internally and you could chain response to use it in the next operator.

```
Mono<DispatchResponse> execute() {
    return weightService()
            .flatMap(wr -> priceService(wr))
            .flatMap(pr -> dispatchService(pr));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex! Can you please also help, how shall I put error handling for respective services as mentioned in question.

Comment: It depends on the error handling logic, but in many cases you could use `onErrorResume`.

Comment: @Alex What does it mean by spring webflux will subscribe to it? If I am writing a kafka processor as a reactive chain, who will call subscribe?

Comment: Ideally you need to subscribe only once, typically on framework layer. If you are creating reactive flow that is part of webflux web API, cloud gateway, .. subscription logic is part of the webflux framework. in case it's "standalone" logic you would need to subscribe explicitly.